# How can I install an older version of a package via NuGet?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I want to install an older version of a package (`Newtonsoft.Json`). But NuGet rolls back:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 4.0.5
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.5'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Already referencing a newer version of 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
```

How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download old version of package with nuget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628689/download-old-version-of-package-with-nuget)

Answer (score 603, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Uninstall-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Force
```

Followed by:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version <press tab key for autocomplete>
```

Comment: twitterizer uses Newtonsoft.Json, I have to install older without uninstall newer.
 
PM> Uninstall-Package Newtonsoft.Json
Uninstall-Package : Unable to uninstall 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.8' because 'twitterizer 2.4.0.26532' depends on it.

Comment: You didn't mention existing dependencies to the package so I was unware of that: try adding the -Force switch to the uninstall-package command (as edited above)

Comment: Sorry for my missing.
-Force worked and I installed the older one. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: when uninstalling EntityFramework 6 beta to downgrade to version 5 I kept getting messages telling me to restart VS to complete uninstall but doing so didn't remove the message. I just went into packages folder and deleted the remaining empty tree structure from there and it was then successful

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I suspect the EF 6 pkg is doing something that causes this (noticed some AppDomain code for instance in the PowerShell scripts, so likely VS is holding on to some of the dll's)

Comment: I don't see the specific version I need in the dropdown list (7.0.0).  And when I specify the version number it gives an error. Any ideas?

Comment: This may be an unlisted version? Unlisted packages are filtered out of search results and autocomplete.

Answer (score 274):

As of **NuGet 2.8**, there is a feature to **downgrade** a package.

[NuGet 2.8 Release Notes](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.8)

Example:

The following command entered into the Package Manager Console will downgrade the Couchbase client to version 1.3.1.0.

```
Update-Package CouchbaseNetClient -Version 1.3.1.0
```

Result:

```
Updating 'CouchbaseNetClient' from version '1.3.3' to '1.3.1.0' in project [project name].
Removing 'CouchbaseNetClient 1.3.3' from [project name].
Successfully removed 'CouchbaseNetClient 1.3.3' from [project name].
```

**Something to note [as per crimbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206090/how-can-i-install-an-older-version-of-a-package-via-nuget/21741899#comment43303798_21741899) below:**

> *This approach doesn't work for downgrading from one prerelease version to other prerelease version - it only works for downgrading to a release version*

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer as its the best solution with minimal effort.

Comment: Yes, works like a charm, including downgrading all dependencies - perfect

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't work for downgrading from one prerelease version to another prerelease version - it only works for downgrading to a release version.

Comment: @James Roland it'd great if you can highlight the prerelease warning by crimbo on the answer

Answer (score 51):

I've used [Xavier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206090/how-can-i-install-an-older-version-of-a-package-via-nuget/10212667#10212667) quite a bit. I want to add that restricting the package version to a specified range is easy and useful in the latest versions of NuGet.

For example, if you never want `Newtonsoft.Json` to be updated past version `3.x.x` in your project, change the corresponding `package` element in your `packages.config` file to look like this:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="3.5.8" allowedVersions="[3.0, 4.0)" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Notice the `allowedVersions` attribute. This will limit the version of that package to versions between `3.0` (**inclusive**) and `4.0` (**exclusive**). Then, when you do an `Update-Package` on the whole solution, you don't need to worry about that particular package being updated past version `3.x.x`.

The documentation for this functionality is [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning).

Comment: Very useful to prevent NuGet updates from breaking your solution!  (Microsoft.Net.Http v2.1.10, I'm looking at you...)

Comment: I'm looking at JQuery 1.9 & 2.0.

Comment: Microsoft.Owin for me :-)

Answer (score 27):

Now, it's very much simplified in **Visual Studio 2015 and later**. You can do *downgrade / upgrade* within the User interface itself, without executing commands in the Package Manager Console.

1. *Right click on your project* and *go to *Manage NuGet Packages*.
2. Look at the below image.

   - `Select your Package and Choose the Version`, which you wanted to install.

[image: NuGet Package Manager window of Project]

***Very very simple, isn't it?*** :)

Comment: yep! This is the way to go :)

Comment: This only shows recent versions. On packages that is older or have a high turnover you are out of luck

Answer (score 2):

Another more manual option to get it:

```
.nuget\nuget.exe install Newtonsoft.Json -Version 4.0.5
```

Comment: Perfect for those who's programming toolset includes a good programming editor, tail and a web browser =)