# Can I use Nuget to install MVC 4 into Webforms, or is it better to merge MVC config into Webforms, for incremental conversion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, webforms, nuget

Times have changed--now we have Visual Studio 2012, MVC 4, Nuget--and it seems like the procedures in the [Hanselman blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) and the more recent [Channel 9 tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Deep-Integration-of-MVC-and-WebForms) could be enhanced.  Both Hanselman and Kane recommend using DIFF tools to merge MVC functionality into the Web Forms Project (to endow the webform's **.csproj** and **web.config** etc with MVC).  However now that Nuget manages packages, I wonder if it would be easier to merely install MVC 4 into the Web Forms project using Nuget; while of course following the procedures in the blog and the channel 9 demo for incrementally upgrading the Webforms project, including dealing with aspx login controls that postback, ascx user controls, and changing base classes Page to ViewPage and MasterPage to ViewMasterPage.

Has anyone tried to use Nuget to endow a Webforms project with MVC 4, and if so, would you recommend that technique?

***UPDATE***
I am following the Kane method which is an ordered set of guidelines (like modifying a complicated recipe in cooking) and am using ***NuGet*** to avoid some tedium.  The guideline requires you make a *dummy* MVC project and compare it to your ASP.NET project to see what you need to add to your original project. You can add stuff using ***NuGet*** GUI, but that gets you latest stable assemblies versions which may lead to the *dark insane demon of incompatibility*. Instead use the ***NuGet*** console command line to get the *compatible* versions listed in the *dummy* MVC project's packages.config as explained in the following: [How to install an older version of package via NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206090/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-package-via-nuget)