# Azure MVC5 BundleTransformer Less Out of Memory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, less, azure-web-app-service, bundletransformer

I give refresh to my website site and profit to re-write my Css to Less.
The website is a web azure application with MVC 5 and BundleTransformer for the Js and Less.
Everything is fine on local iis10 and iisExpress.

But after the deployment on azure. I win a magnific error 500 with:

```
Exception: BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.AssetTranslationException 
    InnerException: JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsRuntimeException: Out of memory 
    ---> MsieJavaScriptEngine.JsRuntimeException: Out of memory bei MsieJavaScriptEngine.ActiveScript.ActiveScriptJsEngineBase.InvokeScript(Action action) bei 
    JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie.MsieJsEngine.InnerExecute(String code) 
    --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung 
    --- bei JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie.MsieJsEngine.InnerExecute(String code) 
    bei BundleTransformer.Less.Compilers.LessCompiler.Initialize() 
    bei BundleTransformer.Less.Compilers.LessCompiler.Compile(String content, String path, DependencyCollection dependencies, CompilationOptions options) 
    bei BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.InnerTranslate(IAsset asset, LessCompiler lessCompiler, Boolean enableNativeMinification) 
    Message: During translation of LESS-code, readed from the file '/Content/less/light.less', to CSS-code error has occurred. 
    See more details: Out of memory StackTrace: bei BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.InnerTranslate(IAsset asset, LessCompiler lessCompiler, Boolean enableNativeMinification) 
    bei BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.Translate(IList`1 assets) bei BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Translate(IList`1 assets, Boolean isDebugMode) 
    bei BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Transform(IList`1 assets, BundleContext bundleContext, BundleResponse bundleResponse, VirtualPathProvider virtualPathProvider, Boolean isDebugMode) 
    bei BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Process(BundleContext bundleContext, BundleResponse bundleResponse, Boolean isDebugMode) 
    bei System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles) 
    bei System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context) 
    bei System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath) 
    bei System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.EliminateDuplicatesAndResolveUrls(IEnumerable`1 refs) 
    bei System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets)
    bei System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths) 
    bei ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\home\site\wwwroot\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:Zeile 42. 
    bei System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() bei System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() 
    bei System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) 
    bei System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) bei System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() 
    bei System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) 
    bei System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
    bei System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
    bei System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
    bei System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
    bei System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) 
    bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    bei System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) 
    bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
    bei System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
    bei System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) 
    bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) bei System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
```

The only hint I found on the web is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647337/asp-mvc-less-file-gives-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocatio)

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use webessentials / some tools or a grunt task to transform your less file and only  include the css in your StyleBundle ?

Comment: I'd say do the bundling before deploying with something like gulp. It's the vNext way to do it anyway

Comment: I already did the "trick" with webessential but it's to bad it didn't work with the right way. :-s

Answer (score 1):

I switched the engine to

```
<jsEngine name="V8JsEngine" />
```

Now it work on azure :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, on the server is installed an old version of the Internet Explorer (before version 9.0), which does not support the Chakra JavaScript engine.