# How to install older version of Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I recently installed Typescript 1.8 and found too many breaking issues.
So for the time being I would like to install 1.7.
Where can I download it?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

For installing typescript 1.7.5, use

```
npm install typescript@1.7.5
```

Comment: what if I want to use nuget, not node.js?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar, for the nuget, refer :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206090/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-package-via-nuget

Comment: This didn't work. I just get an error that says the version doesn't exist. What did work for me though was to just google for "typescript 1.6 download". This ultimately brought me to download the installer from a link.

Comment: I think this answer is really helpful for you, as you have learned to google your problem...:-)

Comment: A range is specified like this: `npm install typescript@">=3.4.0 <3.6.0"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343886/16940

Answer (score 29):

to install **globally** `npm install -g typescript@1.7.5`

to check open cmd and run 
`tsc -v`

to install it for the **specific** project you are working on change to the directory of your project

`npm install typescript@1.7.5`

and then check your package.json file

If you are using visual studio 2017, it may be using visual studio's version of typescript.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a higher version of typescript and you want to install an older version, you can Uninstall the current version by this command(optional):

```
npm uninstall typescript
```

And then you can install the specific version you want like this for version(3.9.7):

```
npm install typescript@3.9.7
```

for ***Globally*** **Install** or **Uninstall** you can add -g to both of the above commands.

Answer (score 1):

To install an older version of TypeScript, you can use npm or yarn package managers. Here's the step-by-step process:

Determine the specific version of TypeScript you want to install. For example, let's say you want to install version 3.9.7.

Open your command line interface (CLI) and navigate to your project directory.

Run the following command using npm:

```
npm install typescript@3.9.7
```

or using yarn:

```
yarn add typescript@3.9.7
```

This command will install TypeScript version 3.9.7 as a project dependency in your project's node_modules directory.

Verify the installation by running the following command to check the installed TypeScript version:

```
npx tsc --version
```

This command will display the TypeScript version installed in your project.

By following these steps, you can install an older version of TypeScript in your project. Remember to replace "3.9.7" with the specific version you want to install.