# The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.8.0 but 2.8.3 was found instead

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, version, global

I starting getting this error on my Angular app:

> The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.8.0 but 2.8.3
>   was found instead

and when I try to downgrade typescript to the right version doing:

`npm install -g typescript@2.7.2` it says updated 1 package.

when I verify typescript version using 
`npm view typescript version`
I still get 2.8.3

I even tried removing typescript entirely using `npm uninstall -g typescript`

but when I verify typescript version again
`npm view typescript version` I still get 2.8.3

What are the commands to properly purge and restore typescript to a previous version such as 2.7.2?

I'm running node v10.0.0 and npm v6.0.1

When I run `npm list -g typescript` I see the correct version coming 2.7.2 but still version 2.8.3 is installed somehow globally

Comment: Stuck with same issue. I'm running 'ng build' from a Jenkinsfile, and it ends up with typescript 2.9.2. My guess is that it's related to @angular-devkit/build-optimizer having a dependency on typescript ~2.9.1.

Comment: Just found out about this question. If anyone has faced a similar error on other versions, please refer to my post! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216110/the-angular-compiler-requires-typescript-3-4-0-and-3-5-0-but-3-5-3-was-found/57216166#57216166

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should do `npm install typescript@'>=2.7.2 <2.8.0'`. This will install the correct typescript your project needs. Make sure you run this inside your Angular project.

On Windows, you should use double quotes instead of single quotes, like so:

```
npm install typescript@">=2.7.2 <2.8.0"
```

Otherwise, you'll get `The system cannot find the file specified.`.

Comment: This command gives me `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Depending upon your operating system and perhaps your settings, you may need to use double-quotes instead of single quotes: `npm install -g typescript@">=2.7.2 <2.8.0"`

Answer (score 10):

In your project folder run again `npm install typescript@2.7.2` as stated from here:

[Want to upgrade project from Angular v5 to Angular v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970553/want-to-upgrade-project-from-angular-v5-to-angular-v6/49474334)

Then it should work.

Comment: I tried that command before but my version still says typescript 2.8.3

Comment: Please save your typescript dependencies as dev dependencies; otherwise you'll be bundling typescript into your final product.

Answer (score 5):

I did next steps:

- removed package-lock.json;
- npm install -g --save typescript@2.7.2;
- npm uninstall -g --save typescript@2.9.2;
- in package.json, section "devDependencies" updated string with typescript as "typescript": "~2.7.2".

After all above run in project's terminal ng serve --open (I've been using IDEA 2018.1).

Comment: I had 2.7.2 installed globally but got 2.9.2 locally after an update with npm-check-updates. So I just followed your steps omitting the -g option, and now I am able to build my project again. Nice! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I did the following:

- Delete manually the folder node_modules
- Delete manually the file package-lock.json
- In the file package.json be sure to set the dependence of TypeScript as

  ```
   "typescript": "2.7.2"
  ```
- run npm cache clean -f
- run npm install

That work for me.

Comment: I have to defend this solution. This is the only one which consistently works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Installing "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.0.0-beta.4" resolved this issue.
I use "typescript": "3.0.3".

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade, run the following commands in the terminal.

- Install the latest version of NPM

  ```
  npm install npm@latest -g
  ```
- Run audit

  ```
  npm audit
  ```
- Update the NPM

  ```
  npm update
  ```
- Run the NPM run script.

  ```
  npm start
  ```

Now your compiler is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to `typescript 2.9.2 (npm install typescript@2.9.2)` and `re-running ng update --all` still yields the error (twice):

```
Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=2.7.2 <2.10", would install "3.1.3"
Verified that version 2.9.2 of typescript was in node_modules.
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (amongst many others) after updating to macOS Mojave.
Fixed it by removing node_modules and package_lock.json manually, changed in package.json from "typescript": "~2.7.2" to "typescript": "~2.8.0" and ran npm install.

Answer (score 0):

This is just because in your projects `package.json` file has

eg.`"devDependencies": {"typescript": "~2.8.3"
  }`

and in your machine where angular cli installed has `"typescript": "2.7.2"` version.

You can check this by `ng -v` or `ng v`.

So, just open **package.json** **update your typescript version** and `run npm install` and you are done.