# Reference References Old Dll and Throws Error

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using a TwitchLib reference and uses Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.0. Every time I got to the page that calls Twitch lab I get the following error.

Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

I have Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.1 installed in my project.

I have added this to my config to try and resolve the issue.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `..newVersion="7.0.0.0"..`

Comment: Why do you have  `newVersion="7.0.0.0"` and "have Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.1 installed in my project." at the same time?

Comment: I manually added this assembly and did a copy and paste from a version 6.0.0 one above and didnt read it properly.

Answer (score 1):

In the Nuget package manager console:

```
Uninstall-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Force

Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.0.0
```

See here: [How to install an older version of package via NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206090/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-package-via-nuget)

Answer (score -1):

Changed the reference newVersion="7.0.0.0" to newVersion="9.0.0.0" and it seems to have resolved the problem.