# How to downgrade Nuget to previous version

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am not looking to downgrade a Nuget package, but Nuget itself. I am trying do downgrade from 6.2 to 6.1 as 6.2 is causing nuget errors for my project after upgrading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install an older version of a package via NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206090/how-can-i-install-an-older-version-of-a-package-via-nuget)

Comment: @LukeVo no it suggest a solution I explicitly didn't want.

Comment: Can you download it from [here](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)?

Comment: Previous versions of nuget.exe can be downloaded from here(https://www.nuget.org/downloads)

Comment: @LukeVo post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download latest and previous versions of Nuget on their [official download page: https://www.nuget.org/downloads](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)