# Install older NuGet package for entire Visual Studio solution

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget

It's simple enough to install an older version of a NuGet package into a particular project (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628689/download-old-version-of-package-with-nuget)).

However, I can't figure out a way to do this solution-wide.

This is a common enough case now since jQuery went to the parallel 1.x / 2.x release model, where there is a current 1.x release and a current 2.x release which supports only the modern browsers. NuGet only shows the 2.x releases as current, making updating 1.x release a big pain.

Comment: Add NuGet issue here: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3405

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install a package to a specific project using the command line:

```
Install-Package Common.Logging -Version 1.2.0
```

Then right click on your solution and go to manage nuget packages for solution. Go to the installed packages section and install it to the projects you need to.

It's not as simple as doing it in one step but it works.

Comment: Not much better / different than doing one at a time, is it. I hope the NuGet team considers this scenario.