# Third-party applications asks for old assembly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.2

Have a serious problem: need to install a third-party web application. After deploying to my local machine getting the exception:

*Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

The problem is i don't have sources, also nuget packadge manager cannot find anything similar to this version. Installation of Entity Framework ver. 4.2.0 does nothing either.

Any thoughts what and where I should download?

Best regards and thanks a log

Comment: Is .2 not one that waqs coming with a .NET framework?

Answer (score 2):

You find nothing on nuget? HAve you ever tried?

Google.... "Entity Framework 4.2" leads me to...

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.2.0

That is nuget, that is Entity framework and that is 4.2.

Maybe, instead of nuget package manager, you use the nuget tools ;)

[Download old version of package with nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628689/download-old-version-of-package-with-nuget)

tells you how to do that - using the command line (which accepts a version parameter).

Comment: Did this of course. There is only EnitityFramework.dll library. Not the Data.Entity. That's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to install this manually:

1. Open the solution
2. Open the Package Manager Console
3. Type: Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.2.0

This will install the specific package version that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You either need :
a. the assembly referenced
b. the source code to change the reference

I would contact whoever wrote the third-party application and try to resolve it from there.

Comment: No source code available. If exists will not be a problem at all )