# How to get latest jQuery 1.x via Nuget in Visual Studio?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

How can I get latest jQuery 1.x (not the latest 2.x) via NuGet in Visual Studio?
The Manage NuGet Packages Window, when I search for NuGet only offers the latest 2.x package.

Thx in advance

Comment: you can download any version from here http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Install-Package jQuery -Version 1.11.1, in the package manager console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download old version of package with nuget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628689/download-old-version-of-package-with-nuget)

Comment: `Install-Package jQuery1` https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in your Package Manager console type following:

Install-Package JQuery -Version ***Press Tab here to see all version here***

[image]