# why datepicker doesnt show on View?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following view with textbox attached with `jquery datepicker`, this shows the text box with DOB button next to it with `datetime` format label but when click button or click on the textbox it does not show the `datepicker`. How do i fix this?

```
@model dtTest.OrderTime

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>OrderTime</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeZone)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeZone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeZone)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeUTC)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeUTC)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeUTC)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
        $('document').ready(function () {
            $('#TimeUTC').datepicker({
                appendText: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                showOn: 'both',
                buttonText: 'DOB',
                dateFormat: 'dd/dd/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
                maxDate: new Date(2005, 0, 1)
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

my layout file adds the jqueryui bundle

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

bundle files are:

```
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
}}
```

when i click the textbox the browser throws the following error in the console (chrome)

[image]

here is my scripts folder:

[image]

Comment: what error are you getting? please check your browser console.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi sorry for the delay when click in the textbox, this was the error "jquery-ui-1.8.20.js:8569 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined"

Comment: I believe you are using incompatible version of `jquery-ui` with your `jquery`. Which `jquery` version you are using? Also please have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools

Comment: yes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools?answertab=active#tab-top  will help you.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi so i have add that migrate script file?

Comment: just use this command in nuget package manager console `PM > Install-Package jQuery`

Comment: This will help you https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery/

Comment: This will update existing jquery package also.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930568/how-to-get-latest-jquery-1-x-via-nuget-in-visual-studio?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **visual studio**

**Menu > `TOOLS > Library and Package Manager > Package Manager Console`**

`PM > Install-Package JQuery` -**Version Press Tab** here to see all version here.

This **update existing jQuery package** and solve your problem with old jQuery version.

For more check [How to get latest jQuery 1.x via Nuget in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930568/how-to-get-latest-jquery-1-x-via-nuget-in-visual-studio?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: what are the libraries that typically used with MVC so i can DL and have them as a backup

Comment: i lost the css settings of teh datepicker and it shows as transparent control, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Your Scripts folder. Just take whole backup.

Comment: You have backup of folder? then find from that files.