# Upgrade to a specific Package version with NuGet

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

How can I upgrade a NuGet package to a specific version.

This is similar to [Download old version of package with nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5628689/1224069), except I already have a version of the given nuget package installed.

I can't update to the latest version, so I want to update to a specific one.

Do I need to uninstall and than re-install or can I upgrade in one step?

Comment: For me uninstall + install specific version has worked. I think only way you can have problems is if you messed up config. In that case just recreate the project. With just clean install.

Comment: I'd prefer not to `recreate the project` just to update a reference though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I think you need to run the Update-Package command by setting the `Version` flag.

For example:

```
Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.4
```

Here's the full command from the documentation for more reference:

> Update-Package [-Id]  [-IgnoreDependencies] [-ProjectName ] [-Version ] [-Source ] [-Safe] [-IncludePrerelease] [-Reinstall] [-FileConflictAction] [-WhatIf]

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference