# install-package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb fails

Tags: nuget, owin

I am working through Pluralsight course [on OAuth2](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/oauth2-openid-connect-angular-aspdotnet/discussion) and have added a project to the solution.

I used a new Asp.Net 4.5.2 empty template which I have set SSL to true on.
I set the framework back to 4.5 to be consistent with the other projects in the solution.

I run the following in the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> install-package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

The error is:

```
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb'At line:1 char:1
+ install-package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

After studying [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628689/download-old-version-of-package-with-nuget?rq=1) I tried adding the version from the course. Here is the result:

```
PM> install-package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -Version 3.0.1
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.1' with respect to project 'TripCompany.IdentityServer', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Install-Package : Package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'E:\EShared\NuGet'. Please verify all your online 
package sources are available.At line:1 char:1
+ install-package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -Version 3.0.1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId
```

Comment: Nuget is showing that the package source is one I created. Investigating...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turned out that I did not have my package source set to nuget.org

In VS2015 I used Tools->Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings
then selected Nuget Package Manager -> Package Sources and checked nuget.org in the available package sources.

Comment: Solved my problem! Thank you :D

Answer (score 3):

I face the this type of problem for adding new package for VS 2013 it solved by

1. goto Tools->Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings
2. selected Nuget Package Manager->

   - a. General -> clear Package Cache(button at right side).
   - b. Package Sources and checked nuget.org in the available package sources.