# How to use specific version of nuget dll in solution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package

The type `AuthenticationResult` exist in both `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstraction, Version 2.0.0.0`
and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=1.1.2.0`

I want to use Version 1.1.2.0. How do I do this?

Comment: They certainly do not have the same namespace so use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nuget Package Manager console to install packages(which is the easiest way to install) refer to this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628689/download-old-version-of-package-with-nuget) that demonstrates using versioned package installs.

If you are using the option "Manage Nuget Packages for solution" from the Tools/Nuget Package Manager Menu, you can select the version from the drop-down that shows up in the install options when selecting a package to install.

If you have installed both packages (I see they don't have the same namespace), to use the specific package version, you can just import that specific namespace to the class